# iOS String: remove prefix and suffix by CharacterSet

Tags: ios, swift, string, tokenize

For a given `String` in Swift I need to remove prefix and suffix characters that belong to a predefined character set.
I can use `components(separatedBy:)` with the character set and get rid of the empty strings at the beginning and end of the components array. Just wondering if there's a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923360-trimmingcharacters) on the string. From the 'help' text in Xcode on this function: "Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the String characters contained in a given character set."

Here is a unit test example using a custom character set. Notice it only removes characters from the start and end, not the middle (the comma stays):

```swift
import XCTest
class TrimCharacters: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() throws {
        let string = "abcbaHello, World!ccbbaa"
        let charactersToTrim = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abc,")
        XCTAssertEqual(string.trimmingCharacters(in: charactersToTrim), "Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

There are also predefined character sets that can be useful. You can also invert a character set. See [`CharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset)